# How do I estimate the point of fracture of a curve in gnuplot

Tags: iteration, gnuplot, ternary-operator

I want to estimate the point of fracture (x_F) (red circle) via ternary operator to restrict the range of my plot to it.

[Example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHdtk.png)

To achieve a restriction to the X(Y_max)-value the *stats* command in combination with ternary-operator seems to be sufficient:

```
stats 'foo.csv' u 5 nooutput name 'Y_'
stats 'foo.csv' u 4 every ::Y_index_max::Y_index_max nooutput
X_max = STATS_max
plot 'foo.csv' u 4:(($4 <= X_max) ? $5 : 1/0) w l notitle
```

I cannot use the X_max-variable, because there a several points beyond the point of fracture (`x_n > x_F`) due to measurement errors. My idea was to compare the x-entries `$4` to one another and to save the first point which satisfies `$4_prev > $4_curr` and to save it as `x_F=$4_prev`.

Comment: You should remove the reference to your original mechanical engineering problem ("fracture") from the question, *or* explain it. The way it is now, it's just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

A simple delta-function seems to do the trick: `delta(x)=(D=x-old_D,old_D=x,D)` and `old_D=NaN` in combination with the ternary operator `(delta($4)>0 ? $5 : 1/0)` whereas `$5` is the y-value, which will be plotted as long as the difference of two sequent x-values is positive.

Comment: This solution proved to be insufficient because there are data points beyond my point of fracture. [plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oSSRk.png) The _x_-data-points can easily be excluded via the ternary operator. But obviously the condition does not stop at `x_F` and therefore the data points beyond the point of fracture with a `delta($4)>0` are plotted. I suggest I am in need of a kind of a loop to determine the value of `x_F` and to extend my condition to `((delta($4)>0) && ($4 <= x_F) ? $5 : 1/0). So I am back to the original question: How to determine `x_F`?

Answer (score 0):

You want to discard any data point after dx has become negative for the first time, right? You'll need a flag variable, i called it `broken`, which is set after the first occurrence of `dx < 0`:

```
broken = 0
plot dataf us (lastx=thisx, thisx=$4): \
  (broken ? 1/0 :($4 < lastx) ? $5 : (broken=1, 1/0))
```

This uses the comma as "serial evaluator", same as in C, etc.

(Not tested now, as i don't have a suitable data set at hand and was too lazy to create one.)

Update: You can put the assignment broken=0 into the plot

```
plot broken=0, dataf us ....
```

, to be able to `replot`, zoom that plot etc.